# Representing ManyToMany relation in the Admin Panel

Tags: django

I am trying to represent a ManyToMany relation in the Admin panel for the following models:

### models.py

```
class Adress(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField()

class Person(models.Model):
   locations = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
```

### admin.py

```
class PeronsAddressRelation(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Person.locations.through

class PersonInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Person
    inlines = [PeronsAddressRelation]
```

The problem now is that I have many relations so when loading the admin edit page of a Person, it takes a lot of time until the Admin view builds the select box of PersonAddressRelation .

Is there anyway I can show inside of PersonAddressInline the name of the address without it being inside a select box? (just static text with a Delete option).

Answer (score 1):

Check [ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields). Using `raw_id_fields` will tell django admin not to create drop down menu.