# Preventing Django admin panel to show drop-down list in Inline display of ManyToMany relationships

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a self-referencing model in Django 1.5 as shown below:

```
RELATIONSHIP_PARENT = 1
RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED = 2
RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES = (
    (RELATIONSHIP_PARENT, 'Parent'),
    (RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED, 'Blocked'),
) 

class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField("Content", max_length=160, db_index=True)
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self',
        through='Relationship',
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='related_to')

class Relationship(models.Model):
    parent_message = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name='parent_messages')
    child_message = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name='child_messages')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)
```

And I configured Django admin to show me `Relationships` as inline when viewing individual `Message` panel as below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from demo.models import Message, Relationship

class RelationshipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Relationship
    extra = 0
    fk_name = 'parent_message'

class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (RelationshipInline,)

admin.site.register(Message, MessageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Relationship)
```

I intend to store many messages (with a lot of parent-child connections among them) in the table. Whenever I view individual message via Admin panel, I see something like this:

[image]

As shown in the red circle, Django admin collects all messages in the database and display them as drop-down list in the menu. I have read through a few ways to prevent it and the closest that I found is [Representing ManyToMany relation in the Admin Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342624/representing-manytomany-relation-in-the-admin-panel) but when I tried putting `raw_id_fields = ('parent_message', )` under `RelationshipInline` class, it doesn't seem to do anything.

If anyone can recommend me to a link or resource or just show me how to prevent Django from showing every entry/messages in the drop-down list, I would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
class RelationshipFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_queryset'):
            criteria = {} #Your criteria here
            qs = super(RelationshipFormSet, self).get_queryset().filter(**criteria)
            self._queryset = qs
        return self._queryset

class RelationshipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Relationship
    extra = 0
    fk_name = 'parent_message'
    formset =  RelationshipFormSet
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very detailed and direct answer. But since I'm a newbie, I would like to ask what I am supposed to add inside `{}`. Is that a Python code snippet (something like functional language style)? If so, what do I write to block everything else (messages) except the currently set message (in the above pic, it's `message 2`)? Is `raw_id_fields` an option? I understand this may not be answerable and might be too much to ask; I just asked because I'm not sure what's going on. Thank you again. :)

Comment: criteria can be something like: `name__startswith='a'` or something. They are normal filter criteria you would use in any queryset filters. I dont believe you would need `raw_id_fields` in this approach.

Comment: Understood! Thanks a lot for your time and patience in answering. :)

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, could you please check this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242698/how-to-show-date-created-in-django-admin) quickly and confirm if the existing answers are accurate? Thank you @karthikr.

Comment: well, for understanding purposes, it is right. So what is happening is, IDs are auto incremented, and since you have probably only added, (and not deleted anything) it appears as though it is sorted by the order of creation. To verify that, below `search_fields = ['phone_number']` , add another `list_display = ['id', 'phone_number']` and you will see why the order shows up the way it does.

Comment: Thank you, @karthikr. I wanted to confirm with you before I confirm it as a correct answer. Have a good weekend. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `raw_id_fields` should go in the admin class:

**admin.py**

```py
class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (RelationshipInline,)
    raw_id_fields = ('parent_message', )
```